# 率直に and 正直に、how do they differ?

Tags: word-choice, words

I just wanted to know how they were different (tone, formality, implications, etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

正直に means "without hiding", whereas 率直に means "without sugar coating". For example you can say to a child who is apparently hiding some truth "正直に言いなさい", but not "率直に言いなさい".

正直な感想を言いますと would imply the speaker was hiding, or was considering hiding his/her true feelings (or at least could have considered hiding). This is useful as a softener before mentioning something that might upset the listener. 率直な感想を言いますと simply means he/she is being candid, so it can be used for positive things as well.

Few examples:

> 「うちの学生の質はどうですか？」
>   「正直に言いますと、A高校よりは劣るような気がします」

.

> 「このラーメンうまいでしょう」
>   「正直に言いますと、豚骨はあまり好きじゃないんです」

.

> 「日本一の職場と言っても良いのではないか、というのが率直な感想です」

When you say

> 「日本一の職場と言っても良いのではないか、というのが正直な感想です」

It would mean "Really, my honest opinion is that this could be the best workplace in Japan".